# uploading photos to news feed

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, photos, image-uploading, feed

I'm using php api to upload photos and post checkins.
Several weeks ago my photos displayed in News Feed automatically, but not now.
My code:

```
$photo_details = array('message'=> 'TEST');
$file='../uploads/'.$_GET['filename'];
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

By the way my chekins are displayed in News Feed